# Is it possible to remove background on tkinter image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image]

Here is my code.

[image]

png image without background

[image]

Here is a result. Is it even possible to remove image background in tkinter or I have to make same color as on image?

Comment: You can use `Canvas` as the background of window, and then use `Canvas.create_image(...)` to put transparent image inside it.

Comment: Write down your code , don't use image.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Learn [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and do not paste images of code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the basic grey background to you're added picture by tkinter.

So try if it is possible to change you're backround from grey to for example red with:
tag: bg="red", if that is possible, you can just change the color to the blue background.

Label(root,image=self.img, bg="blue")

I tested it and it worked out for me. 
Its not possible as far as i know to use rgb() or the hexadezimal with the transperancy option. 
Gave me back errors.

Its not really transperent but kind of a solution !

Good Luck !

Comment: It's a sample, I want to make image  as a background, but thanks, it's a good solution.